# What exactly is this line doing?

Tags: ruby

I don’t know Ruby at all just wondering what this line specifically is doing

```
bitrate = params[:bitrate] =~ /\A\d+k\z/ ? params[:bitrate] : '3000k'
```

It appears to be validating the input but I’m not sure about the last colon

Just wondering what the code does specifically in plain English

Comment: It's a `ternary` operator.   `(some condition) ? (when true) : (when false)`. See [this info](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/).

Comment: Thank you Paul!  That gives me everything I need to know.  Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the ternary operator in use. It has the form:

```
expr ? expr-when-true : expr-when-false
```

The first condition is evaluated in a boolean context, so anything that's treated as true will yield the first result. Otherwise, the second.

In Ruby you could also write as a one-liner:

```
bitrate = if params[:bitrate] =~ /\A\d+k\z/ then params[:bitrate] else '3000k' end
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  Really neat way to do if then else in only one line.